# Split CSV file on multiple delimiters and then detect duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a csv file with panda. I need to duplicate rows according to number of strings in a given column (could be multiple). Example, using col1 and separator "|":
in_csv:
col1, col2, col3
ABC|EFG, 1, a
ABC|EFG, 1, bb
ABC|EFG, 2, c

out_csv:
col1, col2, col3
ABC, 1, a
EFG, 1, a
ABC, 1, bb
EFG, 1, bb
ABC, 2, c
EFG, 2, c

I tried reading through a loop row by row, using incsv_dt.row1.iloc[ii].split('|') but I believe there should be an easier way to do it. Strings in col1 being seperated by | could be multiple

Thanks

Comment: Limited in editing capability on my phone but I think the new title is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Unsorted and might not work if there are are entries without the '|' in the first column. Creates two dataframes based on 'col1' and then appends them together. Also might not work if there are multiple '|'s in col1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = ['APC|EFG', 'APC|EFG','APC|EFG']
df['col2'] = [1,1,2]
df['col3'] = ['a','bb','c']

# split into two columns based on '|' delimiter
df = pd.concat([df, df['col1'].str.split('|', expand = True)], axis=1)

# create two dataframes with new labels
df2 = df.drop(['col1',1], axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={0: 'col1'}, inplace=True)
df3 = df.drop(['col1',0], axis=1)
df3.rename(columns={1: 'col1'}, inplace=True)

# append them together
df = df2.append(df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup for the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = ['APC|EFG', 'APC', 'APC|EFG|XXX']
df['col2'] = [1, 1, 2]
df['col3'] = ['a', 'bb', 'c']
```

You can first create an new data frame with the split colums. 
Then drop the empty values. This works fine if some values have
multiple splits and some have none.

```
dfs = df['col1'].str.split('|', 
        expand = True).unstack().reset_index().set_index('level_1')[0].dropna().to_frame()
```

To merge this with the original dataframe, make sure, the indexes are the same.
When I tried, the original dataframe had a RangeIndex, so I convert that to
Integer

```
df.index = list(df.index)
```

Then you can merge the data frames on the index and rename the new column back to 'col1'

```
df_result = pd.merge(dfs,
         dfx[['col2', 'col3']], 
         left_index=True, right_index=True, 
         how='outer').rename(columns={0: 'col1'})

print(df_result)
```

Results in

```
  col1  col2 col3
0  APC     1    a
0  EFG     1    a
1  APC     1   bb
2  APC     2    c
2  EFG     2    c
2  XXX     2    c
```